# Python mad lib program

Tags: python

We are creating a python program that takes an file that the user defines (madlib1.txt) and replaces certain parts of this file to a new output file called (story.txt).

The madlib1.txt file is provided and looks like this:

```
After I got out of the shower and dressed, I [past-tense-verb] to the
student center to eat [noun] and [noun] for breakfast. I was [emotion]
to go to my classes as we were learning about [topic] . After dinner I
planned to [activity] .
```

I know how to open the file and have an idea on how to make the output but I am stuck finding out how to find the "[   ]" in the file and replace them. The code needs to stay using somewhat basic concepts.

Here is what the program should look like when ran

```
Enter input filename: madlib1.txt
Enter output filename: story.txt
Enter a past-tense-verb: ran
Enter a noun: green eggs
Enter a noun: ham
Enter a emotion: excited
Enter a topic: loops
Enter a activity: go for a bike ride
```

and the output file will have these new user entered words in place of the brackets

here is my code so far

```
def main():
    #get file name
    fname = input("Enter your filename ")
    infile = open(fname,"r")
    output = input("What should the output file be called? ")
    #reads each line
    for line in infile:
        pastTense, noun, noun, emotion, topic, activity = line.split("[")
```

I don't know how to further approach this program.

edit code I have added

```
fname.readlines()
fname.replace("past-tense-verb")

#user inputs thier own words
pastTense = input("Enter a past tense verb ")
noun1 = input("Enter a noun ")
noun2 = input("Enter a noun ")
emotion = input("Enter an emotion ")
topic = input("Enter a topic ")
activity = input("Enter an activity ")
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a fun assignment! Here's how I would approach the problem:

1. Gather **user input**. You're going to want to come up with a way to keep track of the different types of words a user enters, and fill them in appropriately.
2. **Replace** words in input file. For this, I would use the re module or the str.replace() method to search for the next occurrence of a word type and replace it with the appropriate word.
3. Finally, you're going to want to **output the file somehow**. Either output the program to the screen or write back the edited input file with words replaced.

As a hint, I would save the input words in a `list` or `dict` and iterate through that data structure when you do the substitution.

`str.replace`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

`re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Since this is a homework assignment, I don't want to be too specific, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Edit: These two lines demonstrate the use of `f.read()` and `str.replace()`:

```
instring = infile.read()
instring = instring.replace('[noun]', word, 1)
```

Add that just after the `infile = open(fname,"r")` statement.

Comment: how would i go about using the str.replace with my "madlib1.txt"

Comment: Not quite. `open()` returns a file object. First you need to convert it to a string (using `read()` or `readlines()`). After that, you can just do `file_as_string.replace('[noun]', word, 1)` for example, which will replace the first instance of `[noun]` with `word`.

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Still a little confused but thanks for the help so far! So would I need a .replace(...) for every bracketed portion that needs replaced?  here is what i added. not sure if it is right.  fname.readlines()
    fname.replace("past-tense-verb")




    #user inputs thier own words
    pastTense = input("Enter a past tense verb ")
    noun1 = input("Enter a noun ")
    noun2 = input("Enter a noun ")
    emotion = input("Enter an emotion ")
    topic = input("Enter a topic ")
    activity = input("Enter an activity ")

Comment: thanks for your help. i dont want to bug you with my tedious questions. Hopefully i can figure this out. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! You're not bugging me, I just want to make sure that I don't solve the problem for you since it is homework. You're off to a great start. Good luck!